# What did people call and pronounce Jesus in Jesus' time

Tags: life-of-jesus, name-of-jesus

I see that the letter 'J' cant be pronounced in Hebrew or its parent Aramaic, Hence I wanted to know how was Jesus called by people in those days of Jesus.

Please given evidence from the Gospels only.

Comment: Also, check out http://christianity.stackexchange.com/search?q=name+of+jesus

Comment: And also related: http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/9696/what-is-the-significance-of-the-name-jesus and http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/7062/why-is-jesus-name-pronounced-differently-in-each-language

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure you can give evidence from the Gospels regarding the pronunciation of Jesus.  That's a linguistical thing.  It's like trying to explain sound to a deaf person.  Unless the original Gospels were audio-books, we have to make our best guess linguistically today.

That being said, the Greek for Jesus, which is used in the Bible is Ἰησοῦς.  The pronunciation of the word is three syllables, "Ee-ay-soos".

There are also variations of his name based on the role his name may play within a sentence (subject, direct object, indirect object, etc), but the main pronunciation, when Jesus name is used as the subject is, to the best of our knowledge, what I have described above.